# Flutter: Adding Video calling and Server / cloud video call recording to telemedicine app

Tags: flutter, webrtc, agora.io, call-recording, videocall

I am creating a telemedicine service and am designing the App using Flutter. We need it to have video calling facility and also, we would need to record the video calls for quality assurance and customer service requests.

I understand from the Agora website that we can use the Agora Flutter SDK to add a video calling option, but I can't understand how can I implement the call recording part of things.

Can you please help in suggesting how can we add the record to cloud / local recording functionality.

Is there any other way we should look at to implement this instead of using Agora?

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For video recording Agora has its own cloud recording SDK. Which can be integrated to your existing flutter app.To record your live stream/call you will need your own Linux server to perform this function.

https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Recording

You can refer the above link that includes a sample application that is using Agora Cloud Recording SDK.